Problem consuming SOAP service. [Apache Camel 4.8.0 - Camel-Spring-Boot - CXF-SOAP - WSS4J - Programmatically]
I was hoping to get your support to solve my problem and try to identify the reason why it is not possible to consume a SOAP service from Apache Camel 4.8.0. You see, I am migrating an application from Apache Camel 3.0.0 to 4.8.0, and I should mention that with the same configuration I have, this consumption was working.
I am following next migration guide: https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-4-migration-guide.html
I noticed that some libraries has changed, so I replaced it on my project. Now I'm working with this Gradle Dependencies:
implementation group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-cxf-soap', version: '4.8.0'
implementation group: 'org.apache.wss4j', name: 'wss4j', version: '2.1.7', ext: 'pom'
implementation group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-ws-security', version: '3.6.4'

@WebService definition:
import jakarta.jws.WebParam;
import jakarta.jws.WebService;

@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://ExposedComputation", name = "ExposedComputation")
public interface ExposedComputation {
    String processExposedComputation(
        @WebParam(name = "computationId", targetNamespace = "")
        java.lang.String computationId,
        @WebParam(name = "inputXml", targetNamespace = "")
        java.lang.String inputXml,
        @WebParam(name = "arg2", targetNamespace = "")
        java.lang.String arg2
    );
}

CxfEndpoint Configuration:
import org.apache.camel.component.cxf.common.DataFormat;
import org.apache.camel.component.cxf.jaxws.CxfEndpoint;
import org.apache.cxf.Bus;
import org.apache.cxf.BusFactory;
import org.apache.cxf.ext.logging.LoggingOutInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor;
import org.apache.wss4j.dom.WSConstants;
import org.apache.wss4j.dom.handler.WSHandlerConstants;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
public class CxfEndpointConfiguration {

    @Value("${expose-computation.auth.user}")
    private String endpointUser;

    @Value("${expose-computation.auth.password}")
    private String endpointPassword;

    @Value("${expose-computation.endpoint}")
    private String endpointUrl;

    @Bean(name = "exposedComputationEndpoint")  //Notice the CxfEndpoint Bean name
    public CxfEndpoint getExposedComputationEndpoint() {
        CxfEndpoint cxfEndpoint = new CxfEndpoint();
        Bus bus = BusFactory.getDefaultBus();

        cxfEndpoint.setAddress(endpointUrl);
        cxfEndpoint.setDataFormat(DataFormat.CXF_MESSAGE);
        cxfEndpoint.setServiceClass(ExposedComputation.class);
        cxfEndpoint.setBus(bus);

        Map<String, Object> outProps = new HashMap<>();
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN);
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, endpointUser);
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE, WSConstants.PW_TEXT);

        PasswordCallbackHandler.setValueOIPA(endpointPassword);
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS, PasswordCallbackHandler.class.getName());

        WSS4JOutInterceptor wsOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps);
        cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(wsOut);
        cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());

        return cxfEndpoint;
    }
}

Finally, I have these routes:
protected void configureAffiliateSearching() {
    rest()
            .produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .get(URI_AFFILIATE_SEARCH)
            .type(InAffiliateSearchingDto.class)
            .outType(OutAffiliateSearchingDto.class)
            .responseMessage().code(HttpStatus.SC_OK).message("Successful operation").endResponseMessage()
            .responseMessage().code(HttpStatus.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).message("Internal Server Error").endResponseMessage()
            .to("direct:validateParametersAffiliateSearching");
}

protected void validateParametersAffiliateSearching() {
    from("direct:validateParametersAffiliateSearching").routeId("validateParametersAffiliateSearching")
            .to(Constants.Common.BEAN_VALIDATOR)
            .to("direct:buildRequestAffiliateSearching");
}

protected void buildRequestAffiliateSearching {
    from("direct:buildRequestAffiliateSearching").routeId("buildRequestAffiliateSearching")
            .convertBodyTo(InputRequestXml.class) //I defined each mapper with MapStruct for thi convertions: "convertToBody"
            .marshal().jaxb()
            .convertBodyTo(String.class)
            .convertBodyTo(MessageContentsList.class)
            .to("direct:consumeExposeAffiliateSearching");
}

protected void consumeExposeAffiliateSearching() {
    from("direct:consumeExposeAffiliateSearching").routeId("consumeExposeAffiliateSearching")
            .setHeader(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAME, constant("processExposedComputation"))
            .setHeader(Exchange.DESTINATION_OVERRIDE_URL, constant(endpointUrl))
            .to("cxf:bean:exposedComputationEndpoint").id("consumptionAffiliateSearching") //HERE! I'm having the problem.
            .setBody(constant("Llegué hasta la petición")); //Please, ignore this instruction. It just to test.
}

As you can see, I am using the URI format of Apache Camel. However, I am not getting any response, nor any error message in the console. As I will show you below:
Insomnia request/response
Console log
I appreciate any support you can provide to help me find a solution. Thank you very much.
I have checked the endpoint configuration. I have validated that parameters such as URL, username, and password are correct.
Since Apache Camel removed Dozer for transformations and included MapStruct, I made all the necessary modifications to convert the objects. I included camel-spring-boot to manage the dependencies configuration since camel-cdi was removed.
Nothing has worked, and I am also not sure if I am missing any configuration due to I am doing it programmatically and not through the XML files that Apache Camel references.
